# I can just imagine what he is going

Tags: modal-verbs

Consider these sentences, please:

1. *I **can just imagine** what he is going through.*
2. *I **can imagine** what he is going through.*

***Question 1***: Is there any difference between 1 and 2?

***Question 2***: If I were to backshift 1 and 2, how would I backshift them, like this?

3. *I **could just imagine** what he **was** going through* OR *I **could've just imagined** what he **was** going through*.
4. *I **could imagine** what he **was** going through* OR *I **could've imagined** what he **was** going through*.

Answer (score 1):

"Just" in this context works as an intensifier, akin to "truly" and "really", and even "absolutely".

Comment: What's the difference between "*I can **just** imagine what he is going through*" and "*I can **only** imagine what he is going through*"?